# Настроить отладчик в Qt Creator

Tags: mac, qtcreator, qt

Установил Qt Creator c сайта *http://qt-project.org*. При сборке проекта выскакивает окно с надписью: **"Отладчик не задан"**. Как настроить этот отладчик? Я в настройках пытался как-то определить отладчик *GDB*, но все безрезультатно.

Answer (score 2):

Если ты еще не решил свою проблему:

1. Наверняка ты получаешь это сообщение на mavericks. Получаешь
   из-за того, что они убрали из ОС стандартный отладчик, которым
   пользовался QTCreator. Назывался он GDB.
2. На старом креаторе нет возможности изменить отладчик по умолчанию (тебе нужен lldb)
3. Сейчас уже доступен QTCreator 3.0.0 для qt 5.2.0. Он доступен для мак
   и адекватно работает безо всякой работы напильником со стороны
   пользователя после его установки.

Удачи